# Map Reduce spring data configuration

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mapreduce, spring-data

I am trying to run Map Reduce program using Spring data but I keep getting same error as mapper class not found. Can any one please point me what am i doing wrong here. My Application Context looks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:hadoop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd">


        <hadoop:configuration>
            fs.default.name=hdfs://localhost:9000
            mapred.job.tracker=localhost:9001
        </hadoop:configuration>
        <hadoop:job id="wordcountJob" input-path="/input"
            output-path="/outputlst" mapper="com.mapreduce.spring.WordMapper"
            reducer="com.mapreduce.spring.WordReducer" jar-by-class="com.mapreduce.spring.App" />
            <hadoop:job-runner id="runner" run-at-startup="true" job-ref="wordcountJob"/>
</beans>
```

And my pom.xml looks like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringDoop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.mapreduce.spring.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And I am getting following exception

```
 Oct 08, 2013 10:46:57 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context.xml]
Oct 08, 2013 10:46:57 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@7e54864c: startup date [Tue Oct 08 22:46:57 PDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 08, 2013 10:46:57 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [hadoop.properties]
Oct 08, 2013 10:46:57 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ffebe2b: defining beans [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,hadoopConfiguration,wordcountJob,runner]; root of factory hierarchy
Oct 08, 2013 10:46:58 PM org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.JobExecutor$2 run
INFO: Starting job [wordcountJob]
Oct 08, 2013 10:46:58 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient copyAndConfigureFiles
WARNING: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
Oct 08, 2013 10:46:58 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat listStatus
INFO: Total input paths to process : 1
Oct 08, 2013 10:46:58 PM org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader <clinit>
WARNING: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Oct 08, 2013 10:46:58 PM org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy <clinit>
WARNING: Snappy native library not loaded
Oct 08, 2013 10:46:59 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
INFO: Running job: job_201310082141_0002
Oct 08, 2013 10:47:00 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
INFO:  map 0% reduce 0%
Oct 08, 2013 10:47:08 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
INFO: Task Id : attempt_201310082141_0002_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mapreduce.spring.WordMapper
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:718)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mapreduce.spring.WordMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:855)
    ... 8 more
```

I am not sure why I am getting this warning **Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform using builtin-java classes**. Please point me what am I missing here.
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to run on windows?  If yes, do you have cygwin installed?

Comment: No I am running it on my virtual machine and OS is Linux. To be more precise Centos.

Comment: so i'm not sure right away whats wrong. You might try using hadoop's default Mapper/Reducer (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper) just to see if that runs.

Comment: I have removed jar-by-class and add jar path to my application context and it worked.